# How do I check if a page or node (IPublishedContent) uses a specific inherited document type?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a document type **Page** which inherits from a parent document type **Page Base**.

On a rendered page, I can see if the document type is equal to the **Page** document type alias:

```
// Where Model is type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel.
if (Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias == "page")
{
    // My current page uses the "page" document type.
}
```

But how can I check to see if my `IPublishedContent` inherits from **Page Base**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a method for this on the `IPublishedContent` type:

```
// Where Model is type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel.
if (Model.Content.IsDocumentType("pageBase", true))
{
    // My current page uses the "pageBase" document type.
}
```

The overload on `.IsDocumentType()` which accepts a boolean is called `recursive` and it checks to see if your `IPublishedContent` either is the supplied document type, or is derived from that document type.

## Update: However!!

There is a bug using recursive `.IsDocumentType()` if your document types are stored in folders. This issue has been logged [here](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-9997).

Instead, you can use `.IsComposedOf()`:

```
// Where Model is type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel.
if (Model.Content.IsComposedOf("pageBase"))
{
    // My current page uses the "pageBase" document type.
}
```

This method both checks document type compositions and inheritance.

This method differs from recursive `.IsDocumentType()` because it only checks inheritance/compositions, not if the current doc type is the provided alias.

Comment: Nice one. Can you please check your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: Ha ha, I'd love to but I have to leave it another day before accepting my own answer. ;)